# PostgreSQL get json as record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to be able to get a json object as a record.

```
SELECT select row_number() OVER () AS gid, feature->'properties' FROM dataset
```

The output of this query looks like this:

| gid | ?column? json |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{"a": "1", "b":"2", "c": "3"}` |
| 2 | `{"a": "3", "b":"2", "c": "1"}` |
| 3 | `{"a": "1"}` |

The desired result :

| gid | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | null | null |

I can't use json_to_record because i don't know the number of fields. However, all my fields are text.

Comment: could you add the json file to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic way to do that, because the number, type and name of columns have to be known at query parse time. So you would have to do:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER () AS gid,
       CAST(feature #>> '{properties,a}' AS integer) AS a,
       CAST(feature #>> '{properties,b}' AS integer) AS b,
       CAST(feature #>> '{properties,c}' AS integer) AS c
FROM dataset;
```

Essentially, you have to know the columns ahead of time and hard code them in the query.

Comment: That's confirm what i think, I need to know all types, numbers and names of columns